# Solving differential equation involving square of $y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the following differential equation but I am unable to start my solution. So please give me a hint so that I can solve this.
$$ y'(x)^2=r(x)+p(x)y+q(x)y^4$$ I can solve it using finite difference method but can it be solved without numerically.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know which square root to take at each $x $?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your question.

Comment: There is a positive and a negative square root. How should you select which?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us the functions $r(x)$, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$?

Suppose $y$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $k$.

Then $y'$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $k-1$...

and $(y')^2$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $2k-2$.

If $q$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $l$.

Then $qy^4$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $4k+l$.

For parity between LHS and RHS, we need $4k+l \le 2k-2$ or $2k\le -2-l$

If $p$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $m$.

Then $py$ has largest power of $x$ equal to $k+m$.

For parity between LHS and RHS, we need $k+m \le 2k-2$ or $k\ge m+2$